# How to make a random number between -1 and 1 in Java

Tags: java, random, numbers

Trying to figure this out for a while, need a random number that is either -1, 0 or 1. Any help would be great.

Comment: Show your failed attempt here so we can advise how to fix it.

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/363681/generating-random-integers-in-a-specific-range/363732#363732)

Answer (score 0):

```
Random random = ThreadLocalRandom.current();
int randomNumber = random.nextInt(3) - 1;
```

Will do the work

Answer (score 0):

If you use Java < 8 version then old approach will be great for you:

You can use `java.util.Random` class and its method `nextInt(int bound)`. This method generates a random integer from 0 (inclusive) to bound (exclusive). If you want some specific range then you will need to perform some simple math operations:

1. Cut the range: `max - min`
2. If you want to include upper bound value then will add 1: `nextInt((max - min) + 1)` (optional step)
3. Shift the generated number to the value of lower bound: `nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min`

Result:

```
Random r = new Random();
int randomNumber = r.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
```

If you use Java >= 8 version, then there will be easier approach for you:

Now `java.util.Random` class provides other methods according to `Stream` api like:

```
public IntStream ints(int randomNumberOrigin, int randomNumberBound)
public IntStream ints(long streamSize, int randomNumberOrigin, int randomNumberBound)
```

Now you can generate a random integer from origin (inclusive) to bound (exclusive) like that:

```
Random r = new Random();
r.ints(min, max).findFirst().getAsInt();
```

If you want to include upper bound into generating process then:

```
r.ints(min, (max + 1)).findFirst().getAsInt();
```

To prevent producing unlimited stream:

`r.ints(min, (max + 1)).limit(1).findFirst().getAsInt();`

or

`r.ints(1, min, (max + 1)).findFirst().getAsInt();`

Answer (score 0):

answer 1

```
long l = System.currentTimeMillis();
int randomNumber = (int) (l % 3) - 1;
```

answer 2

```
int randomNumber = (int) (Math.random() * 3) - 1;
```

answer 3

```
Random random = new Random();
int randomNumber = random.nextInt(3) - 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at this one

```
 Random r = new Random();

    int n = r.nextInt((1 - -1) + 1) + -1;
    System.out.println(n);
```

it will generate random between the range you want. output will be 1 or 0 or -1.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `int` arrays with [Random](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) class. Store your values in an integer array, and generate random number for the index of the array.

**Sample Code:**

```
final int[] arr = new int[] { -1, 0, 1 };
Random number = new Random();
int n = number.nextInt(arr.length);
System.out.println(arr[n]); //arr[n] will give you random number
```